# Unable to set background image in android activity

Tags: android, android-background

I 'm trying to set background of my main activity in my application something like in this way:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">
```

but the code gives me error:

`The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)`

i don't know why this happens.`@drawable/background` is an image of resolution 1080x1920. I tried to give a color instead of image and it works very well then.But got errors when it comes to an image.Am i missing something?
Please help me out.

Comment: What is your image file? Is it a properly formatted png?

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: As pointed out my image was not `.png` format. I put another image with `.png` format but this time it's not displaying in pre-lollipop devices.Where as it's working in lollipop and after.Working in marsmallow.

Answer (score 0):

Try setBackground in code like:

```
layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
```

Comment: layout is shown in red color ie. error while using layout.